# XML element value with width limitation

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008, t-sql, for-xml-path

I am new to XML and trying to solve the following in SQL Server 2008 using customer table.

`NAME` column has fixed width, so the value (customer name) needs to be separated into more than one representation.

Please see:

- `NAME index="1"`....
- `NAME index="2"`....

Any idea how to tackle this?

Thank you,
Anne

```
<PARTNER>
    <NAME index="1">XEXSY SMALL REALTY LLC</NAME>
    <NAME index="2">AA/NAX TEEEENERGY</NAME>
    <PARTNRTYPE>703884</PARTNRTYPE>
    <ADDRESS>
       <ADDRLINE index="1">544 PACIFIC BLVD</ADDRLINE>
       <CITY>LONG BEACH</CITY>
       <COUNTRY>US</COUNTRY>
       <POSTALCODE>07740</POSTALCODE>
    </ADDRESS>
</PARTNER>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This design is awfull. If you have to the slightest chance to change this, you should...

If you have to stick with this, you can try it like this:

```
DECLARE @mockup TABLE(Name VARCHAR(100),PartnerType INT,Addr VARCHAR(100),City VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @mockup VALUES
 ('This is a very long name which needs to be splitted in smaller parts'
  ,12345
  ,'And this address is very long too, the person has a really long address...'
  ,'Washington')
,('ShortName'
  ,12345
  ,'ShortAddress'
  ,'New York');
```

--You can set the length of the *slices*. The `TOP(20)` is hardcoded and sets an upper limit to the count of parts.

```
DECLARE @PartLenght INT=20;
```

--The query will get a number's table (*tally table*) *on-the-fly* and then use `FOR XML PATH()` to create the XML with the nestings you need.

```
WITH Tally AS
(
    SELECT TOP(20) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS Nr 
    FROM master..spt_values 
)
SELECT (
        SELECT Nr AS [NAME/@index]
              ,SUBSTRING(m.Name,Nr+((Nr-1) * (@PartLenght-1)),@PartLenght) AS [NAME]
        FROM Tally
        WHERE LEN(SUBSTRING(m.Name,Nr+((Nr-1) * (@PartLenght-1)),@PartLenght))>0
        FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
       )
      ,m.PartnerType AS [PARTNERTYPE]
      ,(
          SELECT    
          (
            SELECT Nr AS [ADDRLINE/@index]
                  ,SUBSTRING(m.Addr,Nr+((Nr-1) * (@PartLenght-1)),@PartLenght) AS [ADDRLINE]
            FROM Tally
            WHERE LEN(SUBSTRING(m.Addr,Nr+((Nr-1) * (@PartLenght-1)),@PartLenght))>0
            FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
          )
         ,City AS [CITY]
         FOR XML PATH('ADDRESS'),TYPE
      )
FROM @mockup AS m
FOR XML PATH('PARTNER')
```

The result

```
<PARTNER>
  <NAME index="1">This is a very long </NAME>
  <NAME index="2">name which needs to </NAME>
  <NAME index="3">be splitted in small</NAME>
  <NAME index="4">er parts</NAME>
  <PARTNERTYPE>12345</PARTNERTYPE>
  <ADDRESS>
    <ADDRLINE index="1">And this address is </ADDRLINE>
    <ADDRLINE index="2">very long too, the p</ADDRLINE>
    <ADDRLINE index="3">erson has a really l</ADDRLINE>
    <ADDRLINE index="4">ong address...</ADDRLINE>
    <CITY>Washington</CITY>
  </ADDRESS>
</PARTNER>
<PARTNER>
  <NAME index="1">ShortName</NAME>
  <PARTNERTYPE>12345</PARTNERTYPE>
  <ADDRESS>
    <ADDRLINE index="1">ShortAddress</ADDRLINE>
    <CITY>New York</CITY>
  </ADDRESS>
</PARTNER>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Shnugo, this is very elegant code and save my day!

Comment: just followed your advise. This is the proper etiquette.